# AngularJS, how to extract code from controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers:

```
app.controller("EditController",[
    '$scope','myResource','myMethods', function($scope, myResource, myMethods){...}]);

app.controller("ShowController",[
    '$scope','myResource','myMethods', function($scope, myResource, myMethods){...}]);
```

In both of them, some code is identical, for example:

```
$scope.loading = false;
$scope.mode = "green";
    myResource.get({ "Id": Id }).$promise.then(function(resource){
        $scope.resource = resource;
        $scope.featured = myMethods.getfeatured(resource.offers);
        $timeout(function() {
            alert("finished");
        }, 1000);
    });
```

myResource and myMethods are services.

Is there a way, I can extract the code and include it in both controllers?

EDIT: my services look like this:

```
app.factory('myResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/resource/:Id.json', null,
        {
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
}]);

app.factory('myMethods',['$resource','$location, function($resource, $location) {
    return {
        foo: function() {
            alert("I'm foo!");
        },
        bar: function() {
        alert("I'm bar!");
};
}]);
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of the services.

Comment: @ManuelObregozo I added some services, that look like mine.

Comment: The use `$scope` doesn't allow to use full-fledged JS inheritance patterns. I would suggest to refactor it to controllerAs syntax and `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code

As the services codes are not there I have made it to be simple as below

```
var app = angular.module('removingCommonCodes', []);
app.factory("commonCodes", function() {

    var loading = false;
    var mode1 = "green";
    var mode2 = "red";
return {
  loading:loading,
  mode1:mode1,
  mode2:mode2
  }
});

app.controller("EditController", 
    function($scope,commonCodes) {
    $scope.loading=commonCodes.loading;
    $scope.color=commonCodes.mode1;
});
app.controller("ShowController",  

  function($scope,commonCodes) {

    $scope.loading=commonCodes.loading;
    $scope.color=commonCodes.mode2;

});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fDoesaamXSSrwuFvkGFo?p=preview)

By this method, you can have all your App constants in one factory, web service calls in one factory and so on

Comment: What happens, when in the factory, there are promises, that need to wait for input? Will commonCodes wait for it?

Comment: no if you are using promises, you can return the promise and **defer it in your Controller**

Comment: Definitely I'll update you in another 2 hours as I'm sleeping just now. Hailing in India. If this is helpful upvote and mark answer.

Comment: I do not see many advantages, we need to do the same assignments in every controller, so it needs copy/paste, more sense has just $scope.commonCodes = commonCodes and using it in view by {{commonCodes.loading}} - it is my third proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1: Send controller $scope as parameter to service

Create method in one of services with `$scope` in parameter, then call this method in both controllers. Example call in both controllers:

```
yourService.someDryMethod($scope);
//if we need something more than $scope - then send it also as
//parameter
```

---

### Solution 2: Decorate Your controllers constructor

Second solution is to create function which will run some code before/after our controller code. Example decorator function.

```
function controllerDecorator(controller){

  return function($scope){

      //HERE PASTE YOUR REUSABLE CODE

      //use controller constructor call
      controller.call(this, $scope);
  };
};
```

Using decorator:

```
app.controller("someController", controllerDecorator( function($scope){
...
}) );
```

**Some example code with usage of decorator pattern - https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsikora/6eak4owh/.**

---

### Solution 3: Assign service as $scope property

Set in controller $scope property as service:

```
$scope.someService = someService;
```

Use it in view:

```
{{someService.someProperty}}
```

---

### Solution 4: For ES6 we can use Class and Class inheritance

Comment: using decorator: controller.call(this, $scope) will be immediately called in someController, is that correct?

Comment: @Metaphysiker I edited answer with link to decorator usage - https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsikora/6eak4owh/. This is very efficient way to reuse code and create the same functionality in many controllers. Check it out. And to Your comment question - no it will be called when controller will be created, I am returning function declaration - calling is inside it and it will be called when returned function will be called by angular itself.

Comment: I voted for the answer of aravind, because he came first (and was the only one at the time). But your answer seems more complete. However, since I'm incompetent in judging, is there a way to let someone else decide for the correct answer?

Comment: @Metaphysiker I think You should not change correct answer if this answer helped You, just give +1 to my answer if You think is good. Thanks!